# How to restart terminal/environment variables in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables

Suppose that I redefine some environment variables in a config file. How do I make those go into effect?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 10):

You can always type `source ~/.profile` in your terminal

Answer (score -1):

In case you need to load/reload a particular environment, you can type in your terminal

```
source .env.production  // or any other environment you have
```

If you need to check if a variable is available in the current environment configuration, you can check the value of this var by typing in the terminal

```
echo $MY_VAR
```